# repetir función cada X números en variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero meter un div cada x líneas en una página. 
Ya tengo el contador que me dice las líneas en las que estoy y lo que necesito es repetir la acción cada x líneas.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
var LineaJump = Contarlineas('.Lineas'); 
if (LineaJump >= 35) { $('#Lineas').append('<div class="Espaciador">&nbsp;</div>'); }
```

Hasta ahí cada 35 `LineaJump` mete el salto, pero necesito que sea cada 35, 70,105, etc... O sea, cada 35 líneas, pero no puedo resetear el `LineaJump` para que cada vez que se ejecute se ponga a 0 y que siempre sea 35 ya que la página se recarga cada cierto tiempo y tengo que volver a poner el espaciador.

Supongo que no sirve para nada, pero bueno lo pongo por si os viene bien. el código que cuenta las líneas es este:

```
function Contarlineas(selector) {
    var height = $(selector).height();
    var line_height = $(selector).css('line-height');
    line_height = parseFloat(line_height)
    var rows = height / line_height;
    return Math.round(rows);
}
```

Quizás hay otro método para hacerlo, estoy abierto a cambios.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer algo asi

Declaras una variable fuera de la funcion

```
var numero_lineas = 35;
```

Luego en tu funcion verificar asi

```
if (LineaJump >= numero_lineas){
   //tucodigo
   numero_lineas = numero_lineas + 35;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lineas = 2;
  
  $("#agregar").click(function(){
      if(Contarlineas() == lineas){
         lineas = lineas + 2;
         $("#lineas").append('<div class="Espaciador">Espacio&nbsp;</div>');
      }
      $("#lineas").append("<p>asdasdasd</p>");
      
  });
});

function Contarlineas() {
    return $("#lineas > p").length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Agrege linea">
<button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
<div id="lineas"></div>
```

Comment: no entiendo bien... con eso entiendo que simplemente me sumaria 35 a numero_lineas, pero lo que yo necesito es que cada 35 lineas se vuelva a ejecutar la funcion $('#Lineas').append('<div class="Espaciador">&nbsp;</div>');

Comment: @Killpe edite mi respuesta, deje limite de lineas 2, para que vieras lo que hace

Comment: Funciona genial :) pero no me mantiene la capa espaciadora en el 35 anterior al recargar... mañana lo pruebo un poco mas utilizando el codigo de ejemplo que pones que ahi si funciona y se mantiene. mil gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Al recagar la pagina dices tu? Mmm voy a averiguar lo que pasa es como se recarga la web, tambien los valores quizas podriamos identificar cuando se recarga guardarlo en localStorage o algo asi el ultimo valir

Comment: realmente no cargo toda la pagina, solo recargo un div donde se cargan los resultados he puesto var lineas = 2; fuera de esa recarga para que lo mantenga siempre pero el resto del codigo estan dentro de la parte que recarga, lo mismo tengo que sacarlo de ahi pero claro si lo saco no se recalcula

Comment: no puedo editar mis comentarios así que pongo otro. la recarga la hago con .load de jquery

Comment: Haaa!!! En estos momentos no estoy en un computador, pero mañana seguro que te dejo la respuesta para eso ;)

Answer (score 1):

Estás buscando una condición cuando `LineaJump` sea **divisible** por 35. Es decir, cuando el resto de la división sea cero. Y esto se realiza con el [operador de módulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos) (`%`).

```
const cadaCuantasLineas = 35;

if (LineaJump % cadaCuantasLineas == 0) {

    // insertar el salto de línea acá 

}
```

La condición será válida cuando `LineaJump` sea 0, 35, 70, 105, 140, 175, 210, …

Comment: me pasa lo mismo que con el codigo de sioesi que al recargar el div se pierde, y luego es probable que meta mas de 1 linea por vez, con lo que es posible que una vez sea linea 35 y otra 43 ( lo digo por la división ) el salto de pagina lo tengo que hacer siempre en 35, no se si me explico

Comment: @Killpe eso ya es otra pregunta diferente, sobre código que no publicaste. Puedes formular una nueva pregunta, aunque supongo que podrías ver cuántos espaciadores ya agregaste.